# Converting a multidigital integer from a char array into an integer

Tags: c, char, int, type-conversion

I've build a small program which would convert the given char array to an integer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int char_to_int(char* value);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Illegal argument count!");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("As char array: %s\n", argv[1]);
    printf("As integer: %i", char_to_int(argv[1]));

    return 0;
}

int char_to_int(char* value)
{
    return *value - '0';
}
```

The problem is that when I enter a multidigital number the integer only consists of a single digit number, which is logical, but I have no idea on how to rewrite the code. And I also have no idea why only the first char gets converted.

I know this is pretty basic stuff, but I'd like to know how to implement it correctly.

I'd also like to avoid using the ato() function in the STL.

Reworked code with error handling:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int char_to_int(char* value);

int illegal_conversion = 0;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Illegal argument count!");
        return 1;
    }

    int result = char_to_int(argv[1]);

    if (illegal_conversion)
    {
        printf("Illegal arguments");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("As char array: %s\n", argv[1]);
    printf("As integer: %i", result);

    return 0;
}

int char_to_int(char* value)
{
    int result = 0;
    int negative_integer = 0;

    while (*value)
    {
        if (*value == 43)
        {
            *value++;
            continue;
        }
        else if (*value == 45)
        {
            *value++;
            negative_integer = 1;
            continue;
        }
        else if (*value < 48 || *value > 57)
        {
            illegal_conversion = 1;
            return 1;
        }

        result *= 10;
        result += *value++ - '0';
    }

    if (negative_integer)
        result *= -1;

    return result;
}
```

Comment: How about the `atoi()` function to convert?

Comment: Yeah that's another thing I needed to mention. I'd like to avoid that function since I want to implement that conversion myself. But thanks for mentioning.

Comment: @J...S maybe he wants to learn :)

Comment: @PeterJ I admire that. And by the way your method taught me something. I never thought of incrementing the `char` pointer itself!

Comment: Do you have an idea what this `*value - '0'` does?  If not read about pointer in general and the dereferencing operator in particular.

Comment: Look at the ASCII table. You need to substract 48 in order to get the correct char.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you only return the numerical value of the first digit.

This function converts but without any checks and it works only for the valid non negative decimal numbers, otherwise it is an UB

```
int char_to_int(char* value)
{
    int result = 0;
    while(*value)
    {
        result *= 10;
        result += *value++ - '0';
    }
    return result;
}
```

or a bit smarter one:

```
int char_to_int(char* value, int *res)
{
    int sign = 0;
    int status = 0;
    int result = 0;


    if (value != NULL && res != NULL)
    {
        while (*value)
        {
            switch (*value)
            {
                case '+':
                case '-':
                    if (sign) status = -1;
                    sign = *value == '-' ? -1 : 1;
                    break;
                default:
                    if (!isdigit(*value)) status = -1;
                    if(!sign) sign = 1;
                    *result *= 10;
                    *result += *value - '0';
                    break;
            }
            value++;
            if (status) break;
        }
        if(!status)*res = sign * result;
    }

    return status;
}
```

Comment: Keep programming :)

Comment: Now try yourself: 1. Check if the input string is valid. 2. Sign detection & whitespace removal. Very good exercises

Comment: Don't worry it's perfect. As char array: 324
As integer: 324

Comment: but "dfsff" will give the result and it is not a valid number. -345 will give wrong result as well. Try to sort it out yourself.

Comment: It will be enough to check whether the char is in the range of the ASCII numbers, won't it?

Comment: Not ASCII as every char is in the ASCII range but if it is digit , plus or minus. Special action has to be taken for '-' and  '+'. It needs to be at the beginning

Comment: This works: C:\Dev\C\CharConversion1>CharConversion1
Illegal argument count!
C:\Dev\C\CharConversion1>CharConversion1 32dd
Illegal arguments
C:\Dev\C\CharConversion1>CharConversion1 32
As char array: 32
As integer: 32
C:\Dev\C\CharConversion1>CharConversion1 -32
As char array: -32
As integer: -32

Comment: @Valentin see a bit smarter one in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Reworked code incurs *undefined behavior* in a case where it can be avoided.

Example with (2's complement) `int`

```
char buf[100];
sprintf(buf, "%d", INT_MIN);  // e.g. -2147483648
int y = char_to_int(buf);
```

The `while` loop in `char_to_int()` eventually executes

```
// before
// result: 214748364
// *value: '8'
result += *value++ - '0';
// after
// `int` overflow, this is undefined behavior
```

To avoid, rather than accumulate the answer as a positive value and then later negate if '-' found, accumulate the answer as a negative value and then later negate if '-' not found.  This is less intuitive, yet avoids UB.

Using `unsigned` as an extended range is another way, yet that fails on rare machines where `INT_MAX == UINT_MAX`.  I have only encountered such a machine once and that for for its widest integer.

Other improvements noted in comments.

```
#include <ctype.h>

int char_to_int(const char *value) {  // use const
  int sign = *value;
  if (sign == '-' || sign == '+') {
    value++;
  }

  bool digit_found = false;
  int result = 0;
  // while (isdigit(*value)) {    // avoid this as it is UB when *value < 0, not EOF
  while (isdigit((unsigned char) *value)) { // or (*value >= '0' && *value <= '9')
    result *= 10;
    result -= *value - '0';  // notice the `-=`
    value++;
    digit_found = true;
  }
  if (sign != '-') {
    result = -result;
  }

  // Error detection
  if (*value != '\0' || !digit_found) {
    ; //Handle_Invalid_String();
  }

  return result;
}
```

Note: overflow detection not included.